# How JSP page is compiled and executed on server side?

Tags: jsp

I am familiar with ASP.NET but new to JSP. JSP has a mix-up code style which allows scriptlets to spread in an HTML page. ASP.NET page has a similar code style (but more neat with code-behind).

When page get executed, ASP.NET runtime will compile the HTML code and script code into a single class.

Does JSP do the same thing? If so, it seems serverlet is the ultimate target.

Answer (score 1):

From the very beginning, the servlet container takes the .jsp file and converts it into a servlet (with a .java extension). From that point, the servlet file  (actually, the web server e.g. tomcat, glassfish, jboss etc) is behaving (more or less) like the IIS and aspx file.